# Syntax error: Unexpected Token in React when running npm start

Tags: reactjs

I started getting the syntax error: Unexpected token on my brackets today and when running npm start even though i haven't touched my code in weeks

[this is the compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ex5O.png)

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token (14:7)

  12 |   render(){
  13 |     return(
> 14 |       <>
     |        ^
  15 |        <nav className="Navitems">
  16 |          <h1 className="Navbar-logo">Lauren's Page<i className= "fac fa-react"></i></h1>
  17 |             <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
```

and this is the code:

```
import React, {useState, Component} from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import {Navitems} from './Navitems';

class Navbar extends Component {
  state= { clicked: false}

  handleClick=()=> {
    this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <>
       <nav className="Navitems">
         <h1 className="Navbar-logo">Lauren's Page<i className= "fac fa-react"></i></h1>
            <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
              <i className={this.state.clicked ? 'fas fa-time':'fas fa-bars'}></i>
            </div>
         <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
           {Navitems.map((item, index) =>{
             return (
              <li key={index}>
                <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>
                {item.title}
                </a>
              </li>
             )
           })} 
         </ul>
       </nav>
      </>
    );
  }
};
export default Navbar;
```

I'm just trying to figure out why its showing an error now when it didn't before. Thank you!

Comment: The file contains JSX syntax. Compiler only processes JSX syntax with the `jsx` extension by default.

Comment: try using `<React.Fragment>` instead of `<>`

Comment: try to comment or remove navitems section,if it works ,check what your import
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-burnell-6r7gx?file=/src/App.js:729-1039

Answer (score 1):

You either must be using an old react or babel version check this link out:

Try
importing the Fragment or use <React.Fragment>

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#support-for-fragment-syntax

Comment: Can you mark it as closed